Why does creating a list inside or outside the for loop produce different results?
I'm creating a program that removes duplicate numbers from a list. The point of the exercise is to use "not in" and "in" operators.
The first time I created the code I created the list without the duplicates inside my for loop. I got a strange answer but I knew the code was correct. Moving the list creation outside the for loop produced the correct result and I dont understand why
Correct output:
my_list = [1, 2, 4, 4, 1, 4, 2, 6, 2, 9]

new_list = []
for i in my_list:
    if i not in new_list:
        new_list.append(i)

print("The list with unique elements only:")
print(new_list)

Incorrect output:
my_list = [1, 2, 4, 4, 1, 4, 2, 6, 2, 9]

for i in my_list:
    new_list = []
    if i not in new_list:
        new_list.append(i)

print("The list with unique elements only:")
print(new_list)

My second code didn't work, it just produced the number 9 but my first piece of code (after moving the list creation statement outside the for loop) gave me the correct result.

The statement new_list = [] is initialising the variable new_list as an empty list.
When this is placed inside the loop, the list will be re-initialised (replaced with an empty list) on each iteration.
Whereas when placed outside the loop, the list is initialised first, then updated inside the loop, as expected.

There is no ‘right’ nor ‘wrong’ here, as there are valid use cases for both variations.
However, in your use case, outside the list is the correct choice.

Purely as an aside: If order does not matter another way to remove duplicates from a list is to simply create a set, as:
nodups = set(my_list)

Same approach, but returning a list:
nodups = list(set(my_list))


In the second code, each series that counts the counter i rebuilds the list and empties it, so you only see the last number in it.

You're just recreating new_list as an empty list at each iteration.
